# How to call a python class and methods from Winows command shell correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, class, command-line-arguments

I would like to call a python class from the **windows command shell** (not the python shell!) for this class:

```
class Russ(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Open ComPort")
        return("Done")

    
    def set(self, a, b):     
        print(a+b)
        return("Done")
```

Here I need to instantiate the class "Russ" first in order to open a comport for example. Here it is important that the comport remains open when I call the method "set" with parameters a,b.

Questions:

1. How cann I call and instantiate this class "Russ" from the command shell?
2. How do I call **afterwards** the method "set(a, b) from the command shell, at which the comport is still open?

Unfortunately I only find solution when using the python shell, which is working at this point. But how it looks when I call the class from the windows command shell?